# Why am I not seeing any new artifacts?

Tags: temple-run-2

The same artifacts are appearing again and again. I can't see any new artifacts. For instance I have collected the Infinite Seeker artifact 8 times already.

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed [earlier](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227394/the-same-artifacts-reappearing-in-temple-run-2).

A few updates ago, they tweaked the drop probabilities to make artifacts that you haven't yet collected more likely to drop than those that already have.  If you are playing the latest version, it may just be unfortunate as there definitely can be repeats, but they are not uniformly random as they were earlier.